# Regular Expression Delete Everything Before Line

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to use a regex to delete everything before a certain line in a multi-line string. Is there a regex expression that captures everything *before* (and including) an expression?

```
import re

sample = '''
This is content I need to delete
I do not need any of this.

===

Text I need 
Is here'''

content = re.sub(r'\n===', "", sample)

print(content)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? Could you not just do `sample.split('===')` to separate before the divider and after?

Comment: Because I'm using it within a class and will be searching through different strings with different dividing words (which regex can find). That's a good idea though, I'll keep that in mind if I can't solve it this way.

Comment: If you're using multiple different dividers, you might want to give examples of a few of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be left with just

```
Text I need
Is here
```

(so without any more newlines after the `===`) you can use

```
content = re.sub(r'(.|\n)*===\n*', "", sample)
```

The `(.|\n)*` will get rid of all the text and newlines up to the `===` and the `\n*` will delete the following newlines. You can also leave this last part out if you want to keep the newlines after `===`. So

```
content = re.sub(r'(.|\n)*===', "", sample)
```

will result in

```
             // newline 
             // newline
Text I need 
Is here
```

There will be two newlines left (one directly after the `===` and the second one for the empty line). If you just want one newline before `Text I need...` then use:

```
r'(.|\n)*===\n'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, and thank you for the great explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not grabbing characters which occur before `\n===`. You can use this.

```
content = re.sub(r'.*\n===', "", sample, flags=re.DOTALL)
```